# Python: How do you add a math forumla for all elements in two lists?

Tags: python

I have converted three columns from an Excel document to three lists in Python.
I now wish to make a function, where I loop through all three lists and insert items from each list into a formula.
Example:

list1[1] + list2[1] / list3[1]

There are over 3000 items in all 3 lists, so having to write down a formula for every single item would take forever, so when I want the function, I want the program to automatically go from
list1[1] + list2[1] / list3[1]
to
list1[2] + list2[2] / list3[2],
then to
list1[3] + list2[3] / list3[3]
and so on.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is the (unfinished) code that I wrote so far.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\KOM\Downloads\PO case study 1 - volume factor check NEW.xlsx')
wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\KOM\Downloads\PO case study 1 - volume factor check NEW.xlsx')  # Work Book
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("DPPIV & SGLT2")  # Work Sheet
pack_size = ws1['F']  # Column F
quantity = ws1['H']   # Column H
conversion = ws1['K']   # Column K
column_list_1 = [pack_size[x].value for x in range(len(pack_size))]
column_list_2 = [quantity[x].value for x in range(len(quantity))]
column_list_3 = [conversion[x].value for x in range(len(conversion))]

for (x, y, z) in zip(column_list_1[7:3030], column_list_2[7:3030], column_list_3[7:3030]):
```

Comment: NumPy supports broadcasting operations, it might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy implements well optimized broadcasting operations, so that's what I would use.

```
import numpy as np

...

column_list_1 = np.array(x.value for x in pack_size)
column_list_2 = np.array(x.value for x in quantity)
column_list_3 = np.array(x.value for x in conversion)

result = column_list_1[7:3030] + column_list_2[7:3030] / column_list_3[7:3030]
```

I also took the liberty to make your comprehensions more Pythonic by iterating directly over the elements. You rarely actually need to use list indices in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the x,y,z values you loop through and just append the answer to a new list:

```
answer = []
for (x, y, z) in zip(column_list_1[7:3030], column_list_2[7:3030], column_list_3[7:3030]):
    answer.append(x + y / z)
```